# Mongoose + Everyauth weird behavior

Tags: mongodb, node.js, express, mongoose

Using everyauth, when I login with a never autenticated before user on my website, the following code is launched. Checks if the user is already in my mongodb, if not it writes it. The issue right now is that works for the first authenticated user, then if a second user logins, my joiningUser._id parameters is properly initiated, but all the other parameters of my schema are from the first ever saved user, its like my parameters are never reinitialised... weird, my console.log shows the right new parameters, and not what is actually written in the database. My authentication is done via the everyauth module, I use the express framework.

```
exports.findOrCreateFacebookUser = function(fbUserData, promise){

  User.findOne({_id:fbUserData.id}, function(err, user) {
    if(err) {
      console.log("Error in finding user for auth. Check Db");
      promise.fail(err);
      return;
    }
    else if(user){
      console.log("User found ");
      promise.fulfill(user);     
    }
    else{

      var joiningUser = new User();
      joiningUser._id = fbUserData.id;
      joiningUser.firstName = fbUserData.first_name;
      joiningUser.lastName = fbUserData.last_name;
      joiningUser.email = fbUserData.email;
      //console.log(JSON.stringify(joiningUser));
      joiningUser.save(function(err){
        if(err){
          console.log("Couldnt save new user: " + err);
          promise.fail(err);
          return;
        }
        else{
          console.log("User wasnt existant, it is now created: " + JSON.stringify(joiningUser));
          promise.fulfill(joiningUser);
        } 
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with assigning _id with a forced value. So I created another id for the profile specific id (ex: facebookId).

Answer (score 3):

Use [mongoose-auth](https://github.com/bnoguchi/mongoose-auth). It takes care of the combination of mongoose and everyauth for you.

Comment: I plan on using, but I still would like to know why my code isn't working. It almost sounds like a bug. It saves the right id, but all the other parameters save (first_name...etc) have the values of the previous entered object...why? what am I not seeing?